# Twitter Bootstrap Modal Multiple event firing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This is a odd issue and i have searched for an answer but i could not find one that suited my code.

**EDIT**: This issue happens on a heavy Ajax page, where the page is not refreshed and the Modal are being reused.

Please note my Javascript is a little weak so i am probably approaching this issue wrong

I have found similar issues [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/twitter-bootstrap/kU2WOGqtr1c) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/twitter-bootstrap/TANDpeyEXrs)

Both describe the issue i am having but i just update the calling view on hidden. i don't bind to a button event.

I have multiple Modals defined

```
    <div id="modal_small" class="modal hide fade in">
    </div>
    <div id="modal_large" class="modal hide fade in">
    </div>
```

I reuse these modals. So the modal_large is displaying a Create Form one second and next its showing a list of images you can select from.

I render my modals using the following script passing in the view to be shown in each instance

```
        function show_modal_large(href) {
            $.get(href, function (data) {
                $('#modal_large').html(data);
                $('#modal_large').modal('show');
            });
        };
```

My Goal here is to reuse these modals. and this is where the problem lies i believe

In the "$(document).ready" of the view which is going to display the modal i call this script to bind to the modals 'hidden' event

```
    $('#modal_large').on('hidden', function () {
               // Make Ajax Call - THIS WORKS
    });
```

So imaging you have a list on a view showing your selected images. you then open up a modal and select more images. On Hidden i Update the the selected images on the calling form.

Every thing works fine.

**The Issue:**

The first time i open the modal and close it the 'on hidden' event is fired once. the second time i open and close the modal the 'on hidden' event is call twice, third time three calls and so on. 
If i go off and use the modal for something else with a different 'hidden' event the hidden event is call **four** times for the NEW hidden event, and **Four** times for the old hidden event. After a short while my system just dies with all the ajax calls.

Am i missing something? How should i structure my Code so this does not happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok Figured this out... well kind of. Hope this code is of use to someone else.

As i was binding to the 'hidden' event of the modal, each time it was created i was just adding another binding and another call out to all of the previous binds also.

So to over come this i got rid of the old modal declarations

```
<div id="modal_small" class="modal hide fade in">
</div>
<div id="modal_large" class="modal hide fade in">
</div>
```

and instead of them i dynamically create the modals as i need them like so and passing in a call back for the 'hidden' event

```
      function show_modal_large(href, callback) {
             // create guid to name of this Modal
             var randomNum = guid();
             // create element with guid id
             var elementName = '#' + randomNum.toString();
             $('body').append("<div id=" + randomNum + " class='modal hide fade in'></div>");
             // create Modal and show
             $.get(href, function (data) {
                 $(elementName).html(data);
                 // register call back to 'hidden' event
                 $(elementName).on('hidden', function () {
                     callback();
                     // clean up after hidden
                     $(elementName).unbind();
                     $(elementName).remove();
                 });
                 $(elementName).modal('show');
             });
         };

         function s4() {
             return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
                        .toString(16)
                        .substring(1);
         };

         function guid() {
             return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
                    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
         }
```

I got the Guid creation from [Stackoverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

This works great for me. And solves MY the issue.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use .one instead of .on and the event you are binding will only ever fire once.

Comment: in the above instance, one would not have worked as i actually need to be able to call the event multiple times