# Randomly show a pop up window bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website with a picture with different pop up windows. The pop up windows are made with bootstrap modal pop up. The website has 34 pop up windows when someone clicks on a leaf in the picture.

What I want is when someone visited the website, randomly one of the 34 pop up window has to be showed.

How can I realize this? 
I use the twitter bootstrap modal pop up window.

Comment: What research have you done into the issue yourself, and what have you already tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873109/twitter-bootstrap-modal-multiple-event-firing

Comment: What content is shown in the modals. An image, a page?

Comment: The modals have text and a image and a link to a external site.

Comment: @IanClark I havent tried anything because I can't find anything about it to make it work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use Bootstrap's modal dialog for that. For your solution to work you may provide a custom startup method, like `$('on', 'load', function () { var popsArray = ...; var popup = Math.random() * popsArray.length; ... })`
That's it. As simple as this.