# Angular/Bootstrap Modal WONT call Twice TypeError: v2.deleteModalProject is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

The goal is to be able to call the modal as many times as the user needs because the modal allows the user to delete content. Issues arises when clicked a second time without a page reload.

I am using angular 1.5.6

I have googled and googled for about two and half hours now.

Ive tried placing a unique div with a random id with jQuery append with no luck, using an example from this stackoverflow question here:

[Twitter Bootstrap Modal Multiple event firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873109/twitter-bootstrap-modal-multiple-event-firing)

Here is my modal HTML;

```
    <div class='modal fade' id='deleteModalProfile' role='dialog'>
      <div class='modal-dialog'>
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class='modal-content'>
            <div class='modal-header'>
              <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
              <h4 class='modal-title'>{{modal.title}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class='modal-body'>
              <p>{{modal.body}}.</p>
            </div>
            <div class='modal-footer'>
              <button ng-show='modal.project' class='btn btn-default' ng-click='removeProject()'>Yes</button>
              <button ng-show='modal.goal' class='btn btn-default' ng-click='removeGoal()'>Yes</button>
              <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>No</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is my function that wont call twice;

```
     $scope.deleteModalGoal = function(goal, index) {
        $scope.modal = {"goal": true, "project": false, "title": "Delete Goal?",    "body": "Do you want to delete " + goal.task + " in " + goal.title + "?"}
        $scope.deleteModalGoalIndex = index;
        $scope.deleteModalGoal = goal;
        $("#deleteModalProfile").modal("toggle");
     }
```

This is my index html;

```
     <div ng-include="'views/modal.html'"></div>
     <button type="button" ng-click="deleteModalGoal(goal, $index)" class="btn btn-danger projectTaskDelete"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Task </button>
```

Please help, I only posted because I am out of options.

Thank you for your time,
Daniel

Comment: are you using angular bootstrap or jQuery bootstrap version?

Comment: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js.     thank you for your time, this is the file of bootstrap I'm running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"TypeError: v2.myFunction is not a function" occurs on a second click when the function has the same name as a variable. Angular's $scope is being overwritten by another variable that is not a function.

I added an "s" to my function name and this fixed the problem.

$scope.deleteModalGoal is assigned in the function $scope.deleteModalGoal, so changing $scope.deleteModalGoal = function()...   to   $scope.deleteModalGoals = function()... fixes this.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12353

Fixed:

```
      $scope.deleteModalGoals = function(goal, index) {
    $scope.modal = {"goal": true, "project": false, "title": "Delete Goal?",    "body": "Do you want to delete " + goal.task + " in " + goal.title + "?"}
    $scope.deleteModalGoalIndex = index;
    $scope.deleteModalGoal = goal;
    $("#deleteModalProfile").modal("toggle");
 }
```

Original:

```
      $scope.deleteModalGoal = function(goal, index) {
    $scope.modal = {"goal": true, "project": false, "title": "Delete Goal?",    "body": "Do you want to delete " + goal.task + " in " + goal.title + "?"}
    $scope.deleteModalGoalIndex = index;
    $scope.deleteModalGoal = goal;
    $("#deleteModalProfile").modal("toggle");
 }
```

Hope that helps someone out there!